# Compress Script Resources of ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, compression

How do you compress Script Resources of ASP.Net? I saw a file there reached up to 255 KB! I tried finding solutions, but so far it only talks about scripting dynamic and static files. I checked the compression temp folder of IIS and found no compressed scripted resource there. That led me to the conclusion that these files are transferred over with high bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running IIS6 the guys at OrcsWeb have a nice wee article -

> http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2004/01/12/57916.aspx

We have customers running the port80 software because they get more control:

> http://www.port80software.com/products/zipenable/
>   http://www.port80software.com/products/httpzip/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about tying something into ASP.net but there are a number of standalone compressors.  [Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) is available as a .Net app.  [JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) is available in a number of languages but none of them .Net, and there's [ShrinkSafe](http://shrinksafe.dojotoolkit.org/) which requires java.  It should be pretty simple to tie any of them into your build process.

Answer (score 1):

the best would be to implement an httpHandler in the web.Config.

see http://blog.madskristensen.dk/post/Optimize-WebResourceaxd-and-ScriptResourceaxd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out the JSCompress task in the MSBuild Community Tasks (http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/). It'll strip out the whitespace from a JS file for you.